# How to make a new structure in order to group based on value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, object

i have the following json:

```
[
    {
      'con': 'Usa',
      'city': 'ny',
      'town':'as'
    },
    {
      'con': 'Ger',
      'city': 'ber',
      'town':'zd'
    },
    {
      'con': 'Usa',
      'city': 'la',
      'town':'ss'
    }
  ]
```

and i want to recreate this json into new structure in order to not have a same value of 'con', the new structure should be like this:

```
[{
        "con": "usa",
        "area": [{
            "city": "ny",
            "town": "as"
        }, {
            "city": "la",
            "town": "ss"
        }]
    },
    {
        "con": "ger",
        "area": [{
            "city": "ber",
            "town": "zd"
        }]
    }
]
```

do you have idea how to do this. thanks

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is using the function `Array.prototype.reduce` to group by `country` along with the function `Object.values` to extract the grouped objects.

```js
let arr = [{    'con': 'Usa',    'city': 'ny',    'town': 'as'  },  {    'con': 'Ger',    'city': 'ber',    'town': 'zd'  },  {    'con': 'Usa',    'city': 'la',    'town': 'ss'  }],
    result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a, {con, ...rest}) => {
      (a[con] || (a[con] = {con, area: []})).area.push(rest);
      return a;
    }, Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```